# Dynamic imports: importing a css module depending

Tags: reactjs, css-modules, dynamic-import

I would like to import dynamically a css module depending on a prop that is passed through the component

My js file is a like this

```
import css from './MenuItem.module.styl'
/* .... */
const MenuItem = ({ node, isTitle, isHeader, pathname, hoveredItem }) => {      

  const linkClasses =
    classNames(css.someClass, {[css.someOtherClass]: isHeader})

  const subItemsContainerClasses = classNames(css.someClass, {[css.someOtherClass]: isHeader})

  const itemsContainerClasses = classNames(css.someClass, {[css.someOtherClass]: isHeader})



  return (
    <div className={itemsContainerClasses}>
      /* etc */
    </div>
  )
}
```

It is getting really messy so I would like to import a different css module depending on the isHeader prop

How and where would I do that? It should be inside the component but if I useEffect, how would I reference the `css` part

Edit:

I tried this

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (isheader) {
      import css from './MenuItemHeader.module.styl'
    } else {
      import css from './MenuItemFooter.module.styl'
    }
  });
```

but I get an error that import statements should be at the begging of the file

And I tried

```
const [css, setCss] = useState({});

useEffect(() => {
    if (isHeader) {
      import('./MenuItemHeader.module.styl')
        .then((response) => {                    
          setCss(response) 
        })
    } else {    
      import('./MenuItemFooter.module.styl')
        .then((response) => {                    
          setCss(response) 
        })
    }
  });
```

And I get no errors but the styles are not applied

Comment: Do you really want to load css files dynamically even if this can affect performance and user experience ? Imagine, that your user by clicking button have to wait until all css file loads and applies (read the topic "Critical rendering path").

Comment: But you can import both and then use them by conditions. Yes, Iit increase the first loading, but it doesn't affect loading when user using site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this

```
import  firstCssModule from './MenuItem.firstModule.styles';
import  secondCssModule from './MenuItem.secondModule.styles';

/* ... */

const resolvedStyle = isHeader ? firstCssModule.someClass : secondCssModule.someClass;
```

### classnames

```js
const firstClasses =
    classNames(firstCssModule.someClass, {[firstCssModule.someOtherClass]: isHeader})

const secondClasses = classNames(secondCssModule.someClass, {[secondCssModule.someOtherClass]: isHeader})

const mixedClasses = classNames(firstCssModule.someClass, {[secondCssModule.someOtherClass]: isHeader})
```

### Dictionary and calculated properties

```js
const styles = {
  first: firstCssModule,
  second: secondCssModule
}

const currentModule = 'first';

styles[currentModule].someClass
styles[currentModule].someOtherClass
```

With classnames you can hace something like this and it's ok.

```js
{ [styles[currentModule].someOtherClass]: isHeader }
```

### Validation

```js
const getStyles = moduleName => {
  if (moduleName in styles) {
    return styles[moduleName];
  } else {
    /* moduleName doesn't exist, do something
(for example, return default or throw an error) */
    return styles.first; // default
  }

/* ... */

getStyles(currentModule).someClass;
```

`classnames` in this case:

```js
{ [getStyles(currentModule).someOtherClass]: isHeader }
```

Comment: if there were only a few classes I would, but there are many so I would have to add this condition to all of them. Maybe if there is no other way I will. Thank you

Comment: @user3808307 i updated my answer. i hope it will help now

Comment: added validation

Comment: All of these solutions are not dynamically imported. You're still importing both files. I'm currently looking at a library like loadable which does dynamic component importing and is possibly useful for importing css modules as a component.